# how to annotate rails models in rails version 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, annotate

Im trying to follow some online tutorial on annotating my models in rails. However, it seems all the tutorials are either talking about outdated annotation versions or incorrect installations its a mess.

So far Ive tried the following

1) Added this in the Gemfile

```
gem 'annotate', '2.4.0'
```

2) Then the command:

```
bundle install
```

3) I then saw that the annotation gem was installed and showing up on the command

```
bundle show
```

4) lastly in order to annotate my models I used the command

```
bundle exec annotate --position before
```

At this point I was expecting my models to be annotated however what I got was the following error message:

```
/Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `namespace' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:33:in `load'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:33:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `block in load_tasks'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `each'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `load_tasks'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:423:in `block in load_tasks'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:423:in `load_tasks'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/annotate-2.4.0/lib/annotate.rb:17:in `load'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/annotate-2.4.0/lib/annotate.rb:17:in `load_tasks'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/annotate-2.4.0/bin/annotate:66:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/annotate:19:in `load'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/annotate:19:in `<main>'
```

So feeling completely stumped.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the updated beta version.

```
gem 'annotate', '2.4.1.beta1'
```

Comment: hmm that didn't work, get the message "Could not find gem 'annotate (= 2.4.1.beta) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile."

Comment: Try running `bundle update annotate` after you have changed the version number in the gemfile. I've found that sometimes the simple `bundle install` doesn't work.

Comment: That worked! Wow this stuff is more complicated than I thought !

Answer (score 0):

Also you may try this gem [annotated-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/annotated-rails).