# i'm getting error in running rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i had typed in cmd of ruby on rails command rails generate controller user name:string email:string
once it is created when i type in rake db:migrate it shows error like this:
     C:\Sites\twinkle>rake db:migrate
   (in C:/Sites/twinkle)
   ==  CreateMembers: migrating ==================================================
    -- create_table(:members)
    rake aborted!
     An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

```
 SQLite3::SQLException: table "members" already exists: CREATE TABLE "members" ("
  id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "email" var
  char(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime)
```

what should i do?

Comment: First check whether members table already exists in your database?

Answer (score 3):

This error means you already have a table called 'members' in your database. Remove your `Members` table and try again. Rails can't 'overwrite' the table so you have to make a new one.

You can drop your table like this:

1. `$rails console`
2. `ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:members)`

Now you can run `rake db:migrate` again. it will work now.

Comment: one more thing after bundle install i'm nt able to run annotate command

Comment: can u explain me what is annotate and why it is used

Comment: Annotate is removed you need to add this to your gemfile instead `gem 'annotate'` then run bundle install again :)

Comment: Here's a tutorial: http://news.railstutorial.org/model-annotation/ if version `2.4.0`doesn't work use `gem 'annotate', '2.4.1.beta1'`

Comment: also look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9654727/1379394

Comment: when i write gem 'annotate' , '2.4.0' it shows error :while executing gem runtime error unknown command annotate

Comment: same type of error coming in 2.4.1.beta1

Comment: Try doing a bundle update.

Comment: that also i tried it is showing error could not find gem 'annotate-models(=1.0.4)' in any of the sources listed in your gemfile

Comment: You have to delete your gem annotate-models and add 'annotate' the annotate-models gem doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Seems table `members` already exists.

Try removing the table from db

Answer (score 0):

See this [Rails DB Migration - How To Drop a Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020131/rails-db-migration-how-to-drop-a-table) for drop your existing table